# Cast to ObjectId failed for user_id

Tags: typescript, express, next.js, mongoose-schema, objectid

I want to create a thread post that once each user creates a thread it will be map to the User model updating the User document by pushing the newly created thread id into the threads array of the User. But I am encountering an error once I want to create a thread. Please kindly assist

Failed to create thread: Thread validation failed: author: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "user_2TXrt6taAgNcj0meuTHUEuxQ364" (type string) at path "author" because of "BSONError"

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwHMK.png)]

I have ensure that the "author" field's value is being assigned correctly and matches the expected data type (ObjectId in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Hey I'm doing the same threads project so just add this segment in `PostThread.tsx`
inside the post thread

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch user data
  fetchUser(userId)
    .then((user) => {
      setUserData(user);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle error
    });
}, [userId]);
```

after change author to userId.id keep the rest same

```
const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof ThreadValidation>) => {
  await createThread({
    text: values.thread,
    author: userId._id,
    communityId: null,
    path: pathname,
  });
});
```

The root cause of this issue was that you were using the custom id field of your User schema instead of the MongoDB-generated `_id` field. To resolve the issue, you needed to fetch and use the actual `_id` value from your user data when creating a thread.

Comment: also don't forgot to get fetchUser function here we previously used in user-actions.ts
or reference 
export async function fetchUser(userId:string) {
    try{
        connectToDB();

        return await User.findOne({id: userId})
    }
    catch(error){
        throw new Error(`failed to fetch user:${error.message}`);
    }

}

Answer (score 0):

As the error mention, `user_2TXrt6taAgNcj0meuTHUEuxQ364` is not a valid object ID. You need to change your mongoose schema so `User` is of types `String`

A [valid object id](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) will look something like `638c6c2875345eefb8aafa28`

In your case,

```
author: { 
type: String,
ref: "User"
required: true, 
},
```

And you need to change the User Schema as well.

Comment: I tried it, still the same error

Comment: Thank you. The problem was my user id I  was passing as props to the PostThread component was invalid

Answer (score 0):

your schema is correct. the error says

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "user_2TXrt6taAgNcj0meuTHUEuxQ364"
```

this `user_2TXrt6taAgNcj0meuTHUEuxQ364` is not a valid mongoose id. you are probably querying MongoDB with this id and MongoDB is throwing this error.

Comment: I can you suggest a solution, I have tried several processes still no head way. Thank you

Comment: my guess is you are redirecting the user to a dynamic page with `/user-objectId`  and in this dynamic route, you are using `user-objectId` to fetch the user

Comment: Yes and store the user thread or post in a Thread array created in the User model .   threads: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"Thread",
        }
    ],

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be really simply - just look at your create-thread -> page.tsx, and look if you pass the right id:

```
return (
  <>
    <h1 className="head-text">Create thread</h1>
    <PostThread userId={userInfo._id} />
  </>
);
```

I also wrote **id** instead of **_id** and that was the problem - was passing the inner `userId` instead of the `ObjectID`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked making `userInfo._id.toString()`